# Pointer to element in std::unrodered_map returns 'Read access violation'

Tags: c++

I Have a `std::unordered_map<std::string, myObject>` named `myObjects`. I have a pointer `ActiveObject` that points to last object that was added to the map, but I want to change `ActiveObject` to chosen element so I created this function:

```
for (auto element : myObjects)
    {
        if (Button("element.first") &ActiveObject != &element.second) //Button labled with name of an object
        {
            ActiveObject = &element.second;
        }
    }
```

This creates a button for every elemeent in `myObjects` that after press should set `ActiveObject` to the correct element in the map, but when I try to access the function of `ActiveObject` like so:
`ActiveObject->myFunction()` after pressing the button I get **Exception thrown: read access violation.
__that was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.**

Heres a code in its original form, I am using ImGui for my gui:

```
void Scene::OnImGuiRender()
    {
        ImGui::Begin("Entities in the scene");
        for (auto en : m_Entities)
        {
            if (ImGui::Button(en.second.GetName().c_str()) && m_ActiveEntity != &en.second)
            {
                m_ActiveEntity = &en.second;
            }
        }
        ImGui::End();

        if(m_ActiveEntity != nullptr) m_ActiveEntity->OnImGuiRender(); //This returns error
        cout << m_ActiveEntity->GetName() << end; //This doesn't print anything but doesn't return error
    }
```

Where m_Entities is an `std::unordered_map<std::string, Entity>`.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve] so that everyone can reproduce your issue without having to guess additional code. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, don't omit observations in favour of your interpretations ("I get and exception thrown").

Comment: In particular, a minimal complete example should include not just a compilable and runnable code file, but also specify what framework(s) you're using (such as what where `Button` comes from).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `for (auto element : myObjects) {}` you are saying that `element` is taken **by value** and you're making a copy of the object in the map. When you later do `ActiveObject = &element.second` you're taking the address of a local temporary. A temporary that's destroyed at the end of the loop.

You should change your loop(s) to take the map entries **by reference**. Change the loop to `for (auto& element : myObjects) {}`. Notice the `auto&` which makes `element` a reference instead of a copy. If you don't intend to modify the map entries you could take them by **const reference** by doing `for (const auto& element : myObjects) {}` instead.